# How do I validate 2 conditions for a single field using Yup validation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, formik, yup

I want to check if the text field in the title has been filled or not and I also want to set the limit of the text box to 300 characters. If I try either of these conditions independently they work. However if I try them both at the same time then the character limit validation gets executed but not the other one.

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({

     title: Yup.string().required().label("Title"),

     title: Yup.string().test('len', 'Title must be less than 300 characters', val => 
            val.toString().length < 300)
   })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing an object to the `.shape` function and having the `title` key in there twice results in the first definition being overwritten.

What you would actually need to do, is to create one entry for `title` and then have all validation logic as the value:

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({

     title: Yup.string()
              .test('len', 'Title must be less than 300 characters', val => 
            val.toString().length < 300)
              .required()
              .label("Title")
})
```

You could also change the test for the length to the built-in `.max` operation:

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({

     title: Yup.string()
              .max(300, 'Title must be less than 300 characters')
              .required()
              .label("Title")
})
```